# Artificial Intelligence algorithm for following scenaio

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I am recording mouse coordinates in a page, up until just before the user leaves the page. Using these mouse coordinates, I want to develop an algorithm that should predict whether the user is leaving the page or not. For this scenario, which machine algorithm would be helpful to achieve this?

Comment: You want to predict what time the user will leave the page (I assume users will eventually leave the page at some time)? Or you'd like to classify the user based on his/her current behavior whether he/she is leaning towards leaving the page or staying on the page?

Comment: @Oscee I would like to classify the user based on their current behavior using mouse coordinates and mouse velocity

Comment: That's the easier case, I guess :) You just have to define "current" ie. how far to go back in time and find some good features (clicks, angle/speed changes, proximity to edge, things like this) and apply one of the techniques mentioned below. Don't try to implement them on your own, though, they are rather complex. Spend that time instead with playing/experimenting with different sets of features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are dealing with classic [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) problem. There is a large variety of algorithms available, and new/improved ones emerge constantly.

Some examples are [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), [Naive Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) and [Decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm).

In classic classification problem - you collect a set of samples and "answers" (left or did not leave the page), and use these samples (called the *training set*) to train your classifier, with the algorithm you chose.

The real problem in the problem you mention is determining what are the *features* you are going to use.

Comment: mouse coordinates like x, y axis and mouse velocity

Comment: @user2607673 If you already know the features, try and use them. However, I believe there is a lot of more features you can use that you did not think of (and neither did I)/

Comment: I am new to machine learning. If you suggest how to start, how to implement that would be great full to me. Thanks

Comment: @user2607673 Don't implement, use an existing in library. There are plenty of those. What language are you using?

Comment: @user2607673 Have a look at Weka (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), it is a machine learning library in Java and there are already a lot of questions and answers about it here on stackoverflow

Comment: @amit php or java any language i am confortable

Comment: @user2607673 Look at weka as suggested, and [libSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) for SVM implementation.

Comment: Is there any libraries in PHP??

Comment: @user2607673 No idea, I am not familiar with PHP. Sorry. (But I assume there are, google around)

Comment: @amit Can you tell me how to give x,y axis coordinates and velocity of mouse as training data to classifier. I mean format. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just apply the output that u needed when he clicks on the exit button or the 'X' on the top left?

Comment: I am giving boundary in a page. When user crossed that boundary this algorithm should predict weather user going to leave the page or not

Comment: You could write a code to check whether the mouse pointer crosses that particular boundary or not right?

Comment: @  Nevin Madhukar K It is not simply like crossing the boundary.. Usually some times users can cross the boundary. But algorithm should tell the intention of the user weather he/she going to close the window or not

Comment: Hmm... did the code in the answer above help you out? 
If so ,i need to check it as well :)
Cuz i just got interested to learn about it.

Comment: Yeah..The above answer help full for me a lot :-)